# Bulk insert in MYSQL DB in GCP

Tags: java, mysql, spring, google-cloud-platform, bulkinsert

I Am using a SQL instance hosted in GCP . I am trying to execute the "LOAD DATA" command from the sql workbench from my local machine . 
Have set the value of "local_infile" to "ON".[image]

But when i execute the command :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "user.csv" 
INTO TABLE gcp_db.user FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

I get the following Error :

```
Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user ‘****’@‘%’ (using password: YES)
```

If i try using "LOCAL" like below

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "user.csv" 
INTO TABLE gcp_db.user FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Get the following error

```
Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

All users in GCP have the same permissions , how do i get this working

Comment: Can you clarify that you are using Cloud SQL or MYSQL instance on GCE?

Comment: Using Cloud SQL